# How to obtain access token from youtube API programmatically in swift?

Tags: swift, youtube, access-token

I need to upload a video to `youtube` from my ios app. I got `access-token` manually from `Google OAuth 2.0 Playground`. But it expires after one hour. So, I want to obtain `access-token` programmatically, but couldn’t implement that. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is Google youtube now days says -

> Note: The YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of
>   March 4, 2014. Please refer to our deprecation policy for more
>   information. Please use the YouTube Data API (v3) for new integrations
>   and migrate applications still using the v2 API to the v3 API as well.

You can try with youtube API -

[Youtube-link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol?csw=1#Uploading_Videos)

Comment: YouTube Data API current version is 3, and there isn’t any bit of code to get access-token. They just superficially explain the process. What I need is, exact method of getting access-token.

Comment: @SultanBukharbay have you tried [https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication] ?

Comment: Yes, I have read everything. But I don’t know how to implement that. For example, here is written: `OAuth 2.0: Your application must send an OAuth 2.0 token with any request that accesses private user data. Your application sends a client ID and, possibly, a client secret to obtain a token. You can generate OAuth 2.0 credentials for web applications, service accounts, or installed applications.` BUT how to write that request is unclear.

Comment: @SultanBukharbay you can generate credential here `https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application`